# I got Required type: Double and Provided type: Void

Tags: java

This is my code. If you go to the line System.out.printl("For Eurofighter Typhoon to fly 4.2 hours, it takes " + (Double.toString(calculateGallons(v:4.2)) + " gallons of fuel")); You'll see that I put two dashes/hyphens on the side of the brackets surrounding the error which in this case is (calculateGallons(v:4.2)).

```
package com.company;

class Aircraft1 {
    int passengers;         // Number of people on board
    int cruiseSpeed;        // Miles per hour
    double fuelCapacity;    // Gallons
    double fuelBurnRate;    // Gallons per hour

    // Method to calculate aircraft endurance

    double calculateEndurance() { // Function for aircraft
        double endurance;

        endurance = fuelCapacity / fuelBurnRate;

        return endurance;

    }


    }

public class Main1 {

            public static void main(String[] args) {


                double EuroFighterTyphoonEndurance; // Variable for F15 Fighter Endurance
                double F15_FighterEndurance; // Variable for F15 Fighter Endurance

                Aircraft EuroFighterTyphoon = new Aircraft();      // Creates object of class aircraft
                Aircraft F15_Fighter = new Aircraft();              // Creates object of class aircraft

                EuroFighterTyphoon.cruiseSpeed = 1550;   // Miles per hour
                EuroFighterTyphoon.passengers = 1;       // Number of people on board
                EuroFighterTyphoon.fuelBurnRate = 9.5;   // Gallons per hour
                EuroFighterTyphoon.fuelCapacity = 56.6;  // Gallons

                F15_Fighter.cruiseSpeed = 1875;  // Miles per hour
                F15_Fighter.passengers = 1;      // Number of people on board
                F15_Fighter.fuelBurnRate = 9.5;  // Gallons per hour
                F15_Fighter.fuelCapacity = 56.6; // Gallons

                System.out.println("For Eurofighter Typhoon to fly for 4.2 hours, it takes: " + (Double.toString--(calculateGallons(4.2))-- + " gallons of fuel"));

                System.out.println("Euro Fighter Typhoon Endurance is: " + EuroFighterTyphoon.calculateEndurance());

                double enduranceF15_Fighter = F15_Fighter.calculateEndurance();

                System.out.println("F15 Fighter Endurance is: " + F15_Fighter.calculateEndurance());
    }

    public static void calculateGallons(double v) {
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you probably want `calculateGallons` to be a method of your `Aircraft1` class, not `Main1`.  So move it into `Aircraft1`, remove the `static` and change `void` to `double`.  Then the top line will be similar to the `calculateEndurance` method.  You'll also have to provide the actual calculation, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `Double.toString(calculateGallons(4.2))`.
`Double.toString` method expects a Double as a parameter, however, your `calculateGallons()` method returns void, hence the error.

You should make `calculateGallons` return a double, and you'll be fine

Answer (score 0):

Your method calculateGallons(double v) returns void.
Try defining it like this:

```
public static double calculateGallons(double v) {
}
```

Then add your return statement with your gallons. 
Also, this line has a typo:

```
 System.out.println("For Eurofighter Typhoon to fly for 4.2 hours, it takes: " + (Double.toString--(calculateGallons(4.2))-- + " gallons of fuel"));
```

Change it to:

```
System.out.println("For Eurofighter Typhoon to fly for 4.2 hours, it takes: " + (Double.toString(calculateGallons(4.2)) + " gallons of fuel");
```

Comment: I feel so silly now. Haha. Oh, and the typo was there on purpose because I thought it'll be hard for people to find the issue so I marked it out. Thank you for helping me so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think your calculateGallons function should be in the Aircraft1 class. Moreover, you need to return a double value from this fiunction but you don't return anything, that's why it tells you that it expect a double value but get void.

Here is a working code based on your code :

```
class Aircraft1 {
int passengers; // Number of people on board
int cruiseSpeed; // Miles per hour
double fuelCapacity; // Gallons
double fuelBurnRate; // Gallons per hour

// Method to calculate aircraft endurance

double calculateEndurance() { // Function for aircraft
    double endurance;

    endurance = fuelCapacity / fuelBurnRate;

    return endurance;

}

public double calculateGallons(double v) {
    return v * this.fuelBurnRate;
}

}

public class Main1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    double EuroFighterTyphoonEndurance; // Variable for F15 Fighter Endurance
    double F15_FighterEndurance; // Variable for F15 Fighter Endurance

    Aircraft1 EuroFighterTyphoon = new Aircraft1(); // Creates object of class aircraft
    Aircraft1 F15_Fighter = new Aircraft1(); // Creates object of class aircraft

    EuroFighterTyphoon.cruiseSpeed = 1550; // Miles per hour
    EuroFighterTyphoon.passengers = 1; // Number of people on board
    EuroFighterTyphoon.fuelBurnRate = 9.5; // Gallons per hour
    EuroFighterTyphoon.fuelCapacity = 56.6; // Gallons

    F15_Fighter.cruiseSpeed = 1875; // Miles per hour
    F15_Fighter.passengers = 1; // Number of people on board
    F15_Fighter.fuelBurnRate = 9.5; // Gallons per hour
    F15_Fighter.fuelCapacity = 56.6; // Gallons

    System.out.println("For Eurofighter Typhoon to fly for 4.2 hours, it takes: "
            + EuroFighterTyphoon.calculateGallons(4.2) + " gallons of fuel");

    System.out.println(
            "Euro Fighter Typhoon Endurance is: " + Double.toString(EuroFighterTyphoon.calculateEndurance()));

    double enduranceF15_Fighter = F15_Fighter.calculateEndurance();

    System.out.println("F15 Fighter Endurance is: " + F15_Fighter.calculateEndurance());
}
}
```